# Search node js array for partial match with variable, return index or value

Tags: arrays, node.js, search, find, contains

Hello all I'm new to node and js - trying to make a small bot for a small discord channel , I've kinda hit a wall and can't find a solution.

I am trying to store user input data and recall it later. So far I have this to store the data as a json file.

```
data[user_id] = value_set
var out_data = JSON.stringify(data);
fs.writeFile('users.json', out_data);
```

And would look like this:

```
{"35978432146597841":"String.1","32146879124653147":"String.2"}
```

Now I want to recall the String.X value later based on the user's id. And this is where I am stuck. I figured I'd need to read the json file and transfer it to an array.

I think I successfully made it an array with the following:

```
var in_data = fs.readFileSync('users.json');
var data = JSON.parse(in_data);

var arr = []
for(var i in data){
arr.push([i, data [i]]);}
```

As... 
    console.log(arr[1]);

shows: 
    ['32146879124653147','String.2']

But I cannot figure out how to search that array by the user's id (user_id) to either locate the index and then split the value or even better just pull the value.

Everything I have tried to find the 'String.X' by the user_id has has failed. 
So what do I need to do to pull 'String.2' if I only know '32146879124653147'.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**SOLUTION**

```
var fs = require("fs");
var in_data = fs.readFileSync('users.json');
var data = JSON.parse(in_data);
var arr = [];

for(var i in data){
    arr.push({
            User:i,
            Input:data [i]
            });
        }
var value = arr.find(x => x.User === id);
var f_value = value.Input;
console.log(f_value);
```

**OR**

```
const userfile = require("./users.json");
var f_value = userfile[userID];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much help from Jay this is the answer I came up with.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var in_data = fs.readFileSync('users.json');
var data = JSON.parse(in_data);
var arr = [];

for(var i in data){
    arr.push({
            User:i,
            Input:data [i]
            });
        }
var value = arr.find(x => x.User === userID);
var f_value = value.Input;
console.log(f_value);
```

**OTHER**

I have since found an easier way to accomplish the above, without fs, or creating an array.

```
const userfile = require("./users.json");
var f_value = userfile[userID];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). In your example, it will return the first key/value that matches, or undefined if there is no match.

```
var in_data = fs.readFileSync('users.json');
var data = JSON.parse(in_data);

let obj = {}
for(var i in data){

obj[i]:data [i];

let value = obj.find(value => id)
//if id = '32146879124653147' 
// then the 32146879124653147: 'String.2' key/value would be returned
```

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but let value = arr.find(value => id) is only returning the first part of the array. So arr[0]. Even for troubleshooting purpose I manually type in value = arr.find(value => '32146879124653147'), it is not returning ['32146879124653147','String.2'] it is returning ['35978432146597841',"String.1']

Comment: I am not sure, I thought that would return the array. Could you store it in a key value pair instead of the array when you build it? arr.push({[i]: data[i]}). then use the find().

Comment: I can try, and thought doing so, but couldn't figure out how. And how would that alter the find().

Comment: Just changing "arr.push([i, data [i]])" to  "arr.push({[i]: data[i]})" didn't change the return. With obj[i]:data [i]; I get an error "Unexpected token :" I added a brace "}" at the end thinking that might be the issue but no change.

Comment: I finally got it thanks for all the help - it led me to figuring it out. I don't know if its the most elegant but it works. I'll post the solution under my question and answer it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to push the items separately and then loop over it skipping by 2 elements in the array.

```
var fs = require("fs");

var in_data = fs.readFileSync('users.json');
var data = JSON.parse(in_data);

var arr = []
for(var i in data){
  arr.push(i);
  arr.push(data[i]);
}

console.log("Printing arr...");
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    console.log("arr[" + i + "]= " + arr[i]);
  }

  // Check if 32146879124653147 is found

  console.log("Checking 32146879124653147...");
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i+=2) {

    if (arr[i] === "32146879124653147") {
      console.log("Found " + arr[i+1]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am probably reading it wrong but the above looks like you need to know the string value. But that will be unknown and is what the user is storing. I will only know the users ID and will be using that to find the data they stored.

Comment: Changed it based on user ID value.

Comment: The first for loop works and prints out each array. Printing arr...
arr[0]= 35978432146597841,String.1
arr[1]= 32146879124653147,String.2   and continues to Checking 32146879124653147... but then it stops nothing is printed after.  If instead of console.log("Found " + arr[i+1]); I do var value = arr[i+1] console.log(value); it prints undefined.